# How to add custom Icon on fresco's rounded border in android

Tags: android, fresco

I am using `Fresco` image loader library and I want to add custom `image` icon on `Fresco's` rounded border only. I have googled to find such functionality but not got any proper solution. Kindly help me that how can it possible. I am attaching `screenshot` and I need such functionality as per my requirement.
[image]

Comment: Add the Icon and the Image inside Relative layout and you can achieve your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresco supports overlays, so just add an overlay to the drawee hierarchy with your icon.

http://frescolib.org/docs/drawee-branches.html#Overlays

For example, in XML you can do something like this:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
  xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
  android:layout_width="40dp"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  fresco:overlayImage="@drawable/your_overlay"
  />
```

You have to position the overlay image accordingly, for example by using a `<bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right" />`, ninepatch, or custom drawable. See also https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html and [How to get gravity 'bottom' working on a drawable in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836901/how-to-get-gravity-bottom-working-on-a-drawable-in-xml)

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer but can you please provide me sample code to get such functionality.